# Ionic 3. Google maps api returns: 'setposition undefined' when I try to move a marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic3

As soon as I run the app in the lab I get the following Error:

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPosition'**

The marker is basically your position on the map. I want the marker to change the position as you move.

Does Ionic support marker.setPostion function?

This is my **home.ts** code:

```
  getPosition(): void{
   this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
    .then(response => {
      this.loadMap(response);
    })
    .catch(error =>{
      console.log(error);
      this.loading.dismiss();
    })
    this.geolocation.watchPosition().subscribe((position) => {
      this.moveMarker(position);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
    }

  loadMap(position: Geoposition){
    let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    let longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    let mapEle: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');

    let myLatLng = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};

    // creates the map
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapEle, {
      center: myLatLng,
      zoom: 12
    });
    //adds the marker
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this.map, 'idle', () => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
      let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: this.map,
        title: 'HI!! IM HERE!!',
      });
      this.marcador = marker;
      mapEle.classList.add('show-map');
      console.log(latitude, longitude);
    });
  }

  moveMarker(position: Geoposition){
    let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    let longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    let coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    this.speed = position.coords.speed * 3.6;
    console.log(latitude, longitude);
    this.marcador.setPosition( coords);
    this.map.panTo(coords);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution, basically I declared the **marker** variable at the begining of the class.

After that I compiled the app and the marker started to move! But because of the watchPosition function the app started to spawn a lot of markers, so I include a simple **If/Else** at the moveMarker function.

This is my final code:

```
export class HomePage {

  marker: any=google.maps.Marker;
  map: any;
  speed: any = 0;
  loading: Loading;
  cont: any=0;

  constructor(
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private geolocation: Geolocation,
    private loadCtrl: LoadingController
  ) {}

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.loading = this.loadCtrl.create();
    this.loading.present();
    this.getPosition();
  }

  getPosition(): void{
   this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
    .then(response => {
      this.loadMap(response);
    })
    .catch(error =>{
      console.log(error);
      this.loading.dismiss();
    })
    this.geolocation.watchPosition().subscribe((position) => {
      this.moveMarker(position);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
    }

  loadMap(position: Geoposition){
    let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    let longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    let mapEle: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');

    let myLatLng = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};

    // creates the map
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapEle, {
      center: myLatLng,
      zoom: 12
    });
    //adds the marker
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this.map, 'idle', () => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
      mapEle.classList.add('show-map');
      console.log(latitude, longitude);
    });
  }

  moveMarker(position: Geoposition){
    let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    let longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    let coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    if(this.cont<1){
    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: coords,
      map: this.map,
      title: 'HI!! HI´M HERE!',
    });
    this.cont=this.cont + 1;
    }
    else{
      this.marker.setPosition(coords);
      this.map.panTo(coords);
    }
    this.speed = position.coords.speed * 3.6;
    console.log(latitude, longitude);
  }

}
```

Comment: this very helping me in same problem..thanks for your answer, but how about in HTML?
because im getting error "Cannot read property 'panTo' of undefined"

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
this.subscription = Geolocation.watchPosition().subscribe(position => {
    if ((position as Geoposition).coords != undefined) {
      var geoposition = (position as Geoposition);
      console.log('Latitude: ' + geoposition.coords.latitude + ' - Longitude: ' + geoposition.coords.longitude);
    } else { 
      var positionError = (position as PositionError);
      console.log('Error ' + positionError.code + ': ' + positionError.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: In what will that fix the issue described in the question? Where should that code be inserted? Please add more information to your answer.